# Как описать тип поля jsonb таблицы в джаве

Tags: java, json, spring, jpa

Есть таблица с типом поля jsonb, какой можно тип применить к полю при описании этой модели на джаве?

Comment: Если вы о PostgreSQL, то такой же как и к просто json.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja json и jsonb вроде различаются и в чем-то json никак не заменит jsonb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант без самописного конвертера.

1. Подключаете в проект библиотеку hibernate-types-52

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
       <version>2.9.10</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Над java-классом вашей сущности необходимо добавить следующие аннотации

   ```
   @TypeDefs({
       @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
   })
   public class YourEntityName {
       //fields, getters, setters, et.c.
   }
   ```
3. Над полем, хранящим jsonb в базе данных добавить аннотации

   ```
   @Type(type = "jsonb")
   @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
   private String raw;
   ```

После этого вы можете объявлять как вам удобно тип поля - строкой, объектом вашего dao-слоя, коллекцией объектов (List), ассоциативным массивом (Map).

Answer (score 1):

Может не совсем правильно понял вопрос, ну да ладно...

Ничего не могу сказать про спринг. Может у него есть своё удобное средство.
Но у голого jpa тоже кое-что имеется. Часто можно сделать конвертер для типа данных, который jpa самостоятельно не поддерживает.

Вот пример для postgres и json:

```
@Converter
public class PgJsonConverter implements AttributeConverter<MyClass, PGobject> {
    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public PGobject convertToDatabaseColumn(MyClass attribute) {
        if (attribute == null) return null;
        try {
            PGobject dbData = new PGobject();
            dbData.setValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(attribute));
            dbData.setType("json");
            return dbData;
        } catch (SQLException | JsonProcessingException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Ошибка конвертора", ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyClass convertToEntityAttribute(PGobject dbData) {
        if (dbData == null) return null;
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(dbData.getValue(), MyClass.class);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Ошибка конвертора", ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Названия методов говорят сами за себя.

Поле в Entity

```
@Convert(converter = PgJsonConverter.class)
private MyClass field;
```

Таким нехитрым способом поле `field` класса `MyClass` будет храниться в базе в поле типа `json`.  Тоже самое, думаю, можно сделать и для `jsonb`.

`@Converter` `@Convert` стандартные аннотации jpa.

Кроме того провайдеры jpa могут предоставлять свои способы решения данной задачи.

`ObjectMapper` - это jackson.

А вот запрос по этому полю придётся составлять на родном SQL, если что.